# What does "DM currencies" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

"Key drivers include: 1) low/negative real rates, 2) the view that the dollar has peaked against DM currencies, and 3) lingering macro risks."

source: http://www.businessinsider.com/ubs-note-on-golds-new-phase-after-brexit-2016-7

I googled it and the result is.... Deutsche Mark. It can't be like that, I think.

Comment: I think this question belongs at http://money.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

It means [developed market](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Developed_market). I had to research it a bit too to find out.